# angular: updating view when input changes + .this/$scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsfiddle

I have a few questions I cant seem to figure out. I tried to make a fiddle to show my problem but I cant seem to get it to work although it is working in my app.(https://jsfiddle.net/6dfyx2og/1/#&togetherjs=KxPTHsH0Pu). Values show up on screen and can be manipulated by the input boxes. But now `$scope.booking.nights` wont update if a user changes the value. (In my app when a user fills out both the arrival date and departure date it calls the function calNights that gives us the number of nights).

can anyone see my error?

Since I was not able to get the fiddle working I will post code here

controller:

```
angular.module('squawsomeApp')
  .controller('BookingCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.values = [1,2,3,4,5];

    // var self = this;

    function parseDate(str) {
      var mdy = str.split('/')
      return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
    }

    function daydiff(first, second) {
      return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);
    }

    var calCheckIn = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('checkin'),
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
        onSelect: function() {
          $scope.booking.checkin = null;
          $scope.booking.checkin = this.toString('MM/DD/YYYY');
          calNights();
        }
    });

    var calCheckOut = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('checkout'),
        minDate: $scope.checkin,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        onSelect: function() {
          $scope.booking.checkout = this.toString('MM/DD/YYYY');
          calNights();
        }
    });

    var calNights = function(){
      console.log('outside')
      $scope.booking.nights = null;
      console.log($scope.booking.nights)
      if ($scope.booking.checkin && $scope.booking.checkout) {
        console.log('inside')
        $scope.booking.nights = daydiff(parseDate($scope.booking.checkin), parseDate($scope.booking.checkout));
        // return daydiff(parseDate(self.booking.checkin), parseDate(self.booking.checkout))
        console.log($scope.booking.nights)
      }
    };

    var calCost = function(){
      if ($scope.booking.nights < 7) {
        $scope.booking.cost = 145;
      } else if ($scope.booking.nights >= 7 && $scope.booking.nights <= 29){
        $scope.cost = 135;
      } else if ($scope.booking.nights >= 29){
        $scope.booking.cost = 120;
      }
    };

    $scope.booking = {
      checkin: null,
      checkout: null,
      guests: null,
      nights: null, //daydiff(parseDate(self.booking.checkin), parseDate(self.booking.checkout))
      cost: null,
      pretotal: this.nights * this.cost,
      tax: 0,
      total: this.pretotal + this.tax
    };

  });
```

html:

```
 <div controller="BookingCtrl">
    <form name="bookingForm" ng-submit="">
        <div class="form-fields">

            <label for="checkin">Check In</label>
            <input id="checkin" name="checkin" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="text" ng-model="booking.checkin">
            <label for="checkout">Check Out</label>
            <input id="checkout" name="checkout" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" type="text" ng-model="booking.checkout">
            <label for="guests">Guests</label>
            <select ng-model="booking.guests" ng-options="value for value in values"></select>

            <ul>
                <li>{{booking.checkin}}</li>
                <li>{{booking.checkout}}</li>
                <li>{{booking.nights}}</li>
                <li>{{booking.guests}}</li>
                <li>{{booking.cost}} x {{booking.nights}}</li>
                <li>Tax</li>
                <li>Total</li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li>{{booking.pretotal}}CND</li>
                <li>{{tax}}CND</li>
                <li>{{booking.total}}</li>
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="bookingForm.$invalid">

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

as an aside I initially I wanted to use the this/self syntax inside the controller instead of using $scope. This worked well but I couldn't get the values to display in the view. (the ones bound to inputs would show up, but that was just due to data binding and they would not show the inital values. If some one could explain why this is please let me know.

ie why this in the controller did not show the values in the view

```
var self = this;

self.booking = {
      checkin: null,
      checkout: null,
      guests:  null,
      nights: null, 
      cost: null,
      pretotal: this.nights * this.cost,
      tax: 0,
      total: this.pretotal + this.tax
    };
```

but this did:

```
$scope.booking = {
  checkin: null,
  checkout: null,
  guests: null,
  nights: null, 
  cost: null,
  pretotal: this.nights * this.cost,
  tax: 0,
  total: this.pretotal + this.tax
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope object ($scope) is what enables the controller and the view to communicate with each other.  If you  put your properties on *self* instead of the scope object, there is no way for the view to use them, because they are properties of the controller itself, not the scope object.  When you data-bind input elements in a view, Angular looks for the bound properties in the scope object that it created and passed to the controller. If it doesn't find them, it will *create* properties in the scope object and bind the inputs to them. On the other hand, if you have a property of the scope object that you have given a value in your controller, then Angular will bind that property to the input that you have data-bound to the property.  Therefore, the input will have an initial value on the page that is whatever your controller set it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this / self syntax - but you should be using ControllerAs Syntax.

```
<div ng-controller="BookingCtrl as book">
  <p>{{ book.booking.checkin }}</p>
</div>
```

Read all bout it in the docs :)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController